# Getting TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while using Map method in python

Tags: python

```
s = [1,2,3,4]
list(map(lambda parameter : parameter*2, s))
```

I am trying to run this simple line of code, but ending up getting

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

can anybody please suggest me a solution for this

Comment: Your code works as is

Comment: @ShlomiF you assigned something to the built-in function `list`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is. I'm guessing (for lack of info) that somewhere above these lines of code you've overridden `list` as an actual list...
Check your code for this kind of error, and if it exists then refactor and rename so as to not use `list` as a parameter in your code.